# ArrayPractice with shifting arrays, generate new arrays populated with even numbers, and more

Tags: java, object-oriented, homework

This is from my second homework assignment in my Data Structures class (in which we use Java), we were simply given the task of filling out the functions shown below (they were empty before) and I was wondering if there are any improvements that could be made to this. I've already submitted it, I just feel like I overcomplicated the assigment's tasks somewhat. Thank you!

```
static void printArray(int[] nums) {
    // This function is complete. Here to help your test
    System.out.print("printArray(): ");
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length;i++)
        System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

static void shiftRightArray(int[] nums) {
    // make change to nums.
    // Shift the elements to the right by 1 position. left most elements goes to the right most pos.
    // nums = [10,2,3,-5]. shiftRightArray(nums) will change it to [-5, 10, 2,3]
    //do opposite of shiftLeftArray, start at last position in array, iterating through element by minusing 1 until reaching index 1
    //create int variable with value of the value of the last element in the array
    int f = nums[nums.length-1];
    for(int i = nums.length-1; i >= 1; i--){
        nums[i] = nums[i-1];
    }
    nums[0] = f;

}

static int[] generateEvenNumbers(int count) {
    // Return a new int array filled with n even numbers starting from 2.
    // eg) generateEvenNumbers(3) returns [2,4,6]
    // eg) generateEvenNumbers(5) returns [2,4,6,8,10]
    //create new array of size = to count parameter
    //use for loop to iterate through each element, then add 1 to the position of that element position then times it by 2
    int[] evenNumsArray = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        evenNumsArray[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
    }
    return evenNumsArray;
}

static int[] insertKeepOrder(int[] nums, int idx, int val) {
    // Return a new int array.
    // insert the given 'val' at index 'idx' pushing numbers to the right.
    //      insertKeepOrder([10,20,30],0,5) will return [5, 10, 20, 30]
    //      insertKeepOrder([10,20,30],1,5) will return [10, 5, 20, 30]
    //create and initalize new array with length of nums + 1 to fit the new int
    //also copied all ints from nums into newNumsOrder using System.arraycopy() instead of using for loop to manually copy them
    int[] newNumsOrder = new int[nums.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(nums, 0, newNumsOrder, 0, nums.length);

    //if statement to handle if the idx is 0, if it is 0, simply shift elements to right, similar to shiftRightArray function, except there is an 0 element spot at the end of the array to fill in already
    //if idx != 0, then we start the for loop at the end of the list (similar to previous case), then iterate until we hit the idx position in the array
    if(idx == 0){
        for(int i = newNumsOrder.length-1; i >= 1; i--){
            newNumsOrder[i] = newNumsOrder[i-1];
        }
        newNumsOrder[idx] = val;
    }else{
        for(int i = newNumsOrder.length-1; i >= idx; i--){
            newNumsOrder[i] = newNumsOrder[i-1];
        }
        newNumsOrder[idx] = val;
    }
    return newNumsOrder;
}

static int[] reverseNew(int[] nums) {
    // Return a new int array that is reversed version of nums
    // eg) reverseNew([1,2,3]) returns [3,2,1]
    // eg) reverseNew([5,1,2,3]) returns [3,2,1,5]
    int[] reversedNums = new int[nums.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < reversedNums.length; i++){
        reversedNums[i] = nums[(nums.length-1)-i];
    }
    return reversedNums;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums1 = new int[] {10,2,3,-5,20,10,4};
    int[] nums2 = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
    printArray(nums1); // expected {10,2,3,-5,20,10,4}
    shiftRightArray(nums1);
    printArray(nums1); //expected {4, 10, 2, 3, -5, 20, 10}
    printArray(generateEvenNumbers(5)); // expected 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
    printArray(insertKeepOrder(nums1, 0, 5)); // expected {5, 4, 10, 2, 3, -5, 20, 10}
    printArray(insertKeepOrder(nums2, 1, 5)); // expected {10, 5, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}
    printArray(reverseNew(nums2)); // expected {100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10}
}
```

Comment: If your teacher set any restrictions on the implementation, please state them in the question. For example, are you allowed to use the Java standard array manipulation functions (or was the subject of the class to learn how to do array manipulation by hand)?

Comment: There were really no restrictions, I was just wondering of better ways to write the program. I'm trying to learn from all possible outlets. I'm only in my second year of college so I'm not TOO far into my learning.

Answer (score 1):

This can make use of the `Stream` API, and is better-expressed that way in some (not all) of your methods.

For multi-line comments like

```
    // make change to nums.
    // Shift the elements to the right by 1 position. left most elements goes to the right most pos.
    // nums = [10,2,3,-5]. shiftRightArray(nums) will change it to [-5, 10, 2,3]
```

just put them in a `/* */`. You might also want to follow JavaDoc syntax for such comments that describe the function's contract.

Delete comments like these:

```
    // This function is complete. Here to help your test

    //do opposite of shiftLeftArray, start at last position in array, iterating through element by minusing 1 until reaching index 1
    //create int variable with value of the value of the last element in the array

    //create new array of size = to count parameter
    //use for loop to iterate through each element, then add 1 to the position of that element position then times it by 2
```

They make the code less legible than having no comment at all, and add no information.

Convert your "expected" descriptions into assertions. The cheap way is to use built-in `assert` though you will need to enable `-ea` on the VM. The more built-up way is to use JUnit. I demonstrate the former.

### Suggested

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    static void printArray(int[] nums) {
        System.out.print("printArray(): ");
        System.out.println(
            Arrays.stream(nums)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
        );
    }

    /**
     make change to nums.
     Shift the elements to the right by 1 position. left most elements goes to the right most pos.
     If nums = [10,2,3,-5], shiftRightArray(nums) will change it to [-5, 10, 2,3]
     */
    static void shiftRightArray(int[] nums) {
        int shifted = nums[nums.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(nums, 0, nums, 1, nums.length - 1);
        nums[0] = shifted;
    }

    /**
     @return a new int array filled with 'count' even numbers starting from 2.
     */
    static int[] generateEvenNumbers(int count) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, count)
            .map(x -> x*2)
            .toArray();
    }

    /**
     Out-of-place insert the given 'val' at index 'idx' pushing numbers to the right.
     insertKeepOrder([10,20,30],0,5) will return [5, 10, 20, 30]
     insertKeepOrder([10,20,30],1,5) will return [10, 5, 20, 30]

     @param nums The array into which the insertion will be done
     @param idx The index at which the insertion will be done
     @param val The value to insert
     @return a new int array.
     */
    static int[] insertKeepOrder(int[] nums, int idx, int val) {
        int[] newNumsOrder = new int[nums.length+1];
        System.arraycopy(nums, 0, newNumsOrder, 0, idx);
        System.arraycopy(nums, idx, newNumsOrder, idx+1, nums.length - idx);
        newNumsOrder[idx] = val;
        return newNumsOrder;
    }

    /**
     @return a new int array that is reversed version of nums
     */
    static int[] reverseNew(int[] nums) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, nums.length)
            .map(i -> nums[nums.length - i])
            .toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums1 = new int[] {10, 2, 3, -5, 20, 10, 4};
        int[] nums2 = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
        printArray(nums1);

        shiftRightArray(nums1);
        assert Arrays.equals(nums1, new int[]{4, 10, 2, 3, -5, 20, 10});

        assert Arrays.equals(generateEvenNumbers(5), new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10});

        assert Arrays.equals(insertKeepOrder(nums1, 0, 5), new int[]{5, 4, 10, 2, 3, -5, 20, 10});

        assert Arrays.equals(insertKeepOrder(nums2, 1, 5), new int[]{10, 5, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100});

        assert Arrays.equals(reverseNew(nums2), new int[]{100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10});
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the comments were from my professor, so I just followed his style. I do prefer using the multi-line comments in any language I use about 99% of the time. Plus I also get points deducted for insufficient comments so I usually like to cover my bases. Thank you for the advice and additions. I'm definitely going to learn something from this addition, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Take "academic code" with a grain of salt. Many courses encourage over-commenting early on. Do what the profs say, but know that industrial best practice can and will differ.

Comment: I figured as much, due to the fact that so many videos of professional projects I watch have a scarcity of comments compared to my assignments. Thank you once again!

Comment: @JacksonKirkpatrick Video tutorials don't have enough time to show proper commenting, as it's not really relevant to the actual technical problem they are solving and professors unfortunately haven't usually ever worked with production code. But that's why we're here. :)